# Why is indentation in empty lines bad?

Tags: c++, git, coding-style, indentation

Every FOSS project I know has rules against trailing whitespace in code. But I think it's very natural to continue the current indentation on the next line:

```
int main()
{
....int a = 42;
....
....return a;
}
```

But git for instance throws warnings anyway. So my question is: Why are those tabs *inside* the current indentation bad?

I'm not looking for answers like "It's always done this way". Let's assume indentation is done *consistently* in the whole project in question.

Comment: it's just wasted bytes. my editor (Komodo) strips those automagically.

Comment: I can afford that ;-)
Stripping them out creates other problems:
The cursor jumps around while traveling through the function and I have to add them again when I insert something...

Comment: @Max, you should investigate your editor's equivalent of `vim`'s `smartindent`, `autoindent`, or `cindent` options. Adding a new line of code in the middle of a function without the correct whitespace already there should be easy and trivial in any reasonable text editor.

Comment: Those are not trailing whitespaces, they are leading ones.

Comment: @sarnold, adding lines _is_ trivial and my editor (kate) automatically adds the correct indentation, but my reflex is to go to the empty line and start typing, and then I have to create the correct indentation manually. I think it's the same in vim. Well, might be high time for new habits ;-)

Comment: @unapersson: While they *are* leading whitespace, your assertion that they are not trailing is false. The two are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Another question: whats the benefit you have from them? Most people won't see any difference, and when editing code, the editor/IDE will autoindent properly anyways.

Comment: I suggest (for safety) to **mention C or C++** explicitly in the question (not only by tagging). In languages like python the rules may be different.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It is probably because merging patches with useless whitespace is harder than it should be.

`diff(1)` and `patch(1)` treat spaces and tabs as important content. (Ask any `Makefile` or `.py` source file -- they *are* important!) And if *your* "blank line" has four spaces on it, and *my* "blank line" has eight spaces on it, any attempt to share patches between us will fail for very trivial reasons.

Granted, if you wholesale change the indentation of a block of code, you'll have to go to some work to make patches apply *anyway*. But trying to track down merge failures on lines that *look* blank is **painful**. (I've wasted too much of my life doing just that. Yes, `vim` `listchars` can help, but reading code with `listchars` on all the time is *also* annoying.)

So people standardize on *no trailing whitespace*. It might not really make sense to worry about a dozen lost bytes here or there from a storage standpoint, but it *really* makes merging patches easier. We could probably just as well standardize on adding trailing whitespace, exactly as you have suggested, and be just as happy, but we might as well standardize on the approach that is as parsimonious as possible.

Comment: You can set vim to specially show trailing whitespace without using listchars all the time.  I forget how to do it, but it's very nice.

Comment: When I read the question I was pretty sure that I wouldn't get a good explanation as an answer. I was wrong. :)

Answer (score 4):

This can also be rude to vi users who are accustomed to using paragraph navigation to jump around through code.  Sometimes I do this when vi and it's quite surprising when I skip several functions because invisible characters said this is actually part of the previous paragraph.

Comment: And it is a nuisance when the opening brace of a function is not at the start of the line - because vi and vim have easy ways to get to the start of a function if the open brace is at the beginning of a line.

Answer (score 3):

I think it boils down to "no redundant hidden surprise bytes in your code plz".

As @sarnold points out, redundant surprise bytes make patching and diffs unnecessarily messy.