# How to indent blank lines when indenting multiple lines in vim?

Tags: vim, indentation

So, if I have text like this:

```
int x() {
int a = 1;

return a;
}
```

Trying to indent the inner part of the function does not indent the blank line. (Using visual mode and >)

How can I change the behavior of vim so that the blank line is also indented?

Comment: Are you saying you *want* a line with only white spaces?

Comment: What exactly does an indented blank line look like, other than unnecessary whitespace bytes bloating your files?

Comment: @Peter Rincker: Yes that is correct!

Comment: @twalberg: It shows saner indentation guides if I have tab show as e.g. pipes. For example: `:set list` and `:set listchars=tabs:|\ `. Also, it doesn't mess up my cursor's position when going up and down and it makes it easier to create a new line with the correct indentation. (Pressing `o` on a completely empty line produces a new completely unindented line.)

Comment: @nijoakim `o`/`O` and `S`/`cc` both work correctly. It is more than likely that you do not have `filetype plugin indent on` in your `vimrc`. Also using white space as you wish will affect useful paragraph motions like `{` & `}` and `ip` & `ap`. Your cursor position should also be fine as vim stores the virtual column so going from a long line to a short line back to a long line does not alter the cursor column. You may want to look into `'virtualedit'` if wish to strictly keep the cursor position. See `:h 'virtualedit'`.

Comment: @PeterRinckner: Yes, your suggestions solves all my problems but one. Indentation guides are still displayed with gaps in them. Reading other discussions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917956/why-is-indentation-in-empty-lines-bad, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727988/python-indentation-in-empty-lines) has convinced me that it may be worth the trade off, though. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Add `set smartindent` in your .vimrc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to offer just a very simple way how to do it. You can try to use blockwise Visual mode with `CTRL-V` (or `CTRL-Q` on Windows) to choose a block you wish to indent (start at column one). Then (you need to have `+visualextra` feature; use `:version` to find out if you have it) you can press <kbd>I</kbd> (I mean `Shift-i`) <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>. Or you can do it by mapping

```
vnoremap <Leader><Key> I<c-t><Esc>
```

More on these [`:h v_b_I`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/visual.txt.html#v_b_I)[`:h i_CTRL-T`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-T).

But I really think you should not use a line with only white spaces.